# group action same thing as homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

A linear group action of a group $G$ on a vector space $V$ is the same thing as a homomorphism from G to the general linear group $GL(V)$.

**attempt:** Suppose a linear group action of a group $G$ on a vector space $V$ is given.  For each $g \in G$ we obtain a map $V → V$, denoted by $\phi(g)$.

Define $\phi(g)(v) = g \cdot v$ for all $v \in V$

. Then $ g \cdot v$  is the given action of the ring element $g$ on the element $v$ of $V$. Where $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$.

Then for all $v,w \in V$ and $a,b \in F$ we have $\phi(g)(av + bw) = g \cdot (av + bw) = g \cdot (av) + g\cdot (bw) = a(g\cdot v) + b(g\cdot w) = a\phi(g)(v) + b\phi(g)(w)$.

So $\phi$ is  a group homomorphism .

Conversely, suppose a homomorphism from G to the general linear group exists. 
Then let $\phi: G → GL(V)$ is  representation of $G$ on the vector space $V$ over $F$.

Can someone please help me? I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: You also have to say that $\phi(g)\in GL(V)$. It should be mentioned that $\phi(g)$ has an inverse, only then will it be a member of $GL(V)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make some comments on your forward proof :

1. You have to first say that each $\phi(g)$ lands in $GL(V)$. That is each $\phi(g)$ is an *invertible* linear transform.
2. You have to show that $\phi:G\to GL(V)$ is a group homomorphism. Which means you have to show that $\phi(g_1g_2)=\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)$. You have only shown that each $\phi(g)$ is a linear transform from $V\to V$

For the converse :

For each $g\in G$, $\phi(g)\in GL(V)$ is an invertible linear transform from $V\to V$. So define the action as $g\cdot v := \phi(g)(v)$ for every $v\in V$.

Now you just have to show that this is a linear action. That is $(g_1g_2)\cdot v=g_1\cdot (g_2\cdot v)$ , $e\cdot v=v$ and $g\cdot(av_1+bv_2)=ag\cdot v_1+bg\cdot v_2$

Comment: That is how I define the action for the forward part

Comment: @user84208 no. you defined the map $\phi:G\to GL(V)$ given the action. I am defining an action given such a $\phi$

Comment: would i then proceed the same way as my approach after defining an action given such $\phi$?

Comment: Almost the same. You just have to check that what you have is in fact a linear action. That is $(g_1g_2)\cdot v=g_1\cdot (g_2\cdot v)$ , $e\cdot v=v$ and $g\cdot(av_1+bv_2)=ag\cdot v_1+bg\cdot v_2$

Comment: Do you a hint for the converse?

Comment: For part $2$) you mentioned $\phi: G → GL(V) $, but then $\phi(g) : V → V $? is this what you mean?

Comment: Also do we have to show $\phi(g_1g_2) = \phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)?$ and  $\phi(g_1) + \phi(g_2) = \phi(g_1 + g_2)?$ I am confuse why they are equal on part 2) of your comment.

Comment: @user84208, sorry that + was a typo. And no, you don't have to prove both things you mentioned above. Just the first one. You are dealing with groups. There is only one group operation for each group. For $GL(V)$ it is composition of functions. Also, yes, $\phi(g)$ is a linear transform from $V\to V$